# Prove that $f(x)=|x-1|^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ iff $n\ge2$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Prove that $f(x)=|x-1|^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ iff $n\ge2$

I tried to compare the limits of the derivative defintion at $x\to1^+$ and $x\to1^-$ but didn't manage. I think that's the (a) way to do it but I'm not sure on the specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=1$, then $\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=-1$. Therefore, $f'(1)$ does not exist.

If $n\geqslant2$, then$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{|x-1|^n}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{|x-1|}{x-1}|x-1|^{n-1}=0,$$since $\frac{|x-1|}{x-1}$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\to1}|x-1|^{n-1}=0$.

Comment: I see I should have split it to $n=1$ and $n>1$ that makes sense :P Thanks.

Comment: @Jason If my answer was useful perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: can't for another minute.